# Audio player in flex

Tags: apache-flex, audio

I want to play Audio in flex application.I am using SWFLoader for it.Is there any other way to load audio into Flex applications.

Thanks & Regards,
Prasanth Babu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [flash.media.Sound](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html#load()) class.

> The `Sound` class lets you work with sound in an application. The `Sound` class lets you create a new Sound object, load and play an external MP3 file into that object, close the sound stream, and access data about the sound, such as information about the number of bytes in the stream and ID3 metadata. More detailed control of the sound is performed through the sound source — the `SoundChannel` or `Microphone` object for the sound — and through the properties in the `SoundTransform` class that control the output of the sound to the computer's speakers.
>
> To control sounds that are embedded in a SWF file, use the properties in the `SoundMixer` class.